# What does 本当たりえる mean

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I am playing the eroge Tsui no Sora and have come across a passage containing this word:

> 当たり前だがノストラダムスの大予言なんて出来の悪い妄想だ。
>
> まともに考えれば小学生にすらわかる事。
>
> だがそんな事は重要じゃない。
>
> [Nostradamus' prophecy is an amateur delusion; even an elementary schooler could work it out if they gave it some serious thought; but that isn't important]
>
> 重要な事は、それを信じる人間にとってそれが**本当たりえる**事だ。
>
> "What is important, is that for the people who believe it, it is true"

This is what I believe it should translate to, but even searching 本当たり gets no results on Google. My vague guess it is combination of 本 + 当たる　+ える but other than 当たる　and 本当 meaning something along the lines of 'it fits' or 'truth', I cannot parse it.

Could someone break this down for me please?　I can provide more of the text before the passage if there is still not enough context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 「重要な事は、それを信じる人間にとってそれが**本当たりえる**事だ。」

I am finding two issues with the phrase 「本当たりえる」.

1) the poor, casual word choice of 「本当」 and

2) the substandard reading of 「たりえる」

It would be a considerably more normal and acceptable
phrase if:

1) 「本当」 were replaced by a less informal 「真実」 and

2) 「たり**え**る」 by 「たり**う**る」

Using kanji, it is 「足り得る」 meaning "to be equal to", "to be comparable to", "to be just as good as".

Thus, my own phrase choice would be 「真実たり**う**る」 or 「真実足り得{う}る」.

With these alterations, the sentence in question could more naturally mean:

> "What is important, is the fact that for the people who believe (Nostradamus), it is as good as true"

Comment: What is substandard and deviant about たりえる？
Also, isn't this the auxiliary [たる](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8B-563315), not the verb 足る?